# Fluent API in TS Class unable to meet Interface's contract

Tags: typescript

I have an open source library which I'm refactoring and have hit an intractable Typescript problem. I consider myself a fairly advanced TS user but this problem just seems impossible.

Summary level the problem is this:

- I have a two classes -- [`SerializedRealTimeQuery`](https://github.com/forest-fire/universal-fire/blob/feature/refresh/packages/serialized-query/src/SerializedRealTimeQuery.ts) and `SerializedFirestoreQuery` -- which implement a Typescript interface called [`ISerializedQuery`](https://github.com/forest-fire/universal-fire/blob/feature/refresh/packages/types/src/%40types/query/ISerializedQuery.ts).
- Both of the concrete classes have effectively the same job but for different databases (Firebase's RTDB and Firestore) and therefore their input params and return values can vary based on this. For this reason, the interface provides generics to allow these variations to co-exist.
- As a "for instance" the class definition for `SerializedRealTimeQuery` is as follows:

  ```
  export class SerializedRealTimeQuery<TModel> 
         implements ISerializedQuery<TModel, IRealTimeApi> { ... }
  ```
- The `TModel` generic is pretty *un*-interesting and I believe can largely be ignored but for context it is there to allow stronger typing of an entity that will be stored in the database but none of the errors are tied to this.
- It is the second generic which is where the trouble begins:

  - There are two types -- [`IRealTimeApi`](https://github.com/forest-fire/universal-fire/blob/feature/refresh/packages/types/src/%40types/database/db-api-derivatives.ts) and [`IFirestoreApi`](https://github.com/forest-fire/universal-fire/blob/feature/refresh/packages/types/src/%40types/database/db-api-derivatives.ts) -- which are just versions of the generic type [`IDatabaseApi`](https://github.com/forest-fire/universal-fire/blob/feature/refresh/packages/types/src/%40types/database/db-api-base.ts). And in the case of `IRealTimeApi` are defined as:

    ```
    export type IRealTimeApi = IDatabaseApi<Database.RTDB>;
    ```
  - These two types are passed into `ISerializedQuery` to tell it which database is being operated on and to help ensure that the right types are used. When we look at the generic definition of `ISerializedQuery` we can see that it takes these two discrete inputs and calculates two more types (`TDb` and `K`):

    ```
    export interface ISerializedQuery<
      /** the data model being serialized */
      TModel extends IModel = IGenericModel,
      /** the type of database it is being serialized down to */
      TApi extends IDatabaseApi = IDatabaseApi,
      TDb extends IDatabase = TApi extends IRealTimeApi
        ? IRtdbDatabase
        : IFirestoreDatabase,
      K = keyof TModel & string
    > { ... }
    ```
  - When passing in the first two generics, the second two are automatically calculated and in **vs-code** it would appear they are calculated correctly.
- The problem is -- however -- that while in my concrete classes I get no warnings/errors about the class being able to *implement* the `ISerializedQuery` interface, during the Fluent API aspects of the class where I return the class as a return value, it says that the class is inconsistent to the interface! An example of that can be seen here:

  [image: error message]
- Generics (1) and (2) are one-for-one the same, and the calculated generics (3) and (4) appear exactly right and should not conflict with types in either the concrete class or the interface. Still somehow the class is not able to be seen as meeting the interfaces specification even though there is no error in the *implements* clause:

  [image: no error in classes implements clause]

### Repo

Above you'll find links the specific files I've mentioned but the repo itself is reachable in the [`feature/refresh`](https://github.com/forest-fire/universal-fire/tree/feature/refresh) branch.

If anyone is interested in cloning and creating their own environment, just be aware it's a monorepo (using Lerna). To set it up though just involves cloning and then:

```sh
# install base deps
yarn
# install package deps
yarn bootstrap
```

Also to see the Typescript errors in the console versus the editor:

```sh
yarn build
```

The build should successfully built the `types` package but then fail on the `serialize-query` package.